WPF Messagebox with Fluent theme
I upgraded my WPF project to .NET 9 and I used fluent theme. Everything is good except the messageboxes. They render with classic windows theme. Is there any way to show them in fluent theme?
MessageBox.Show(...);


https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/basics/user-interface/messagebox

You can just use a window, styled to taste and show dialog. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/dialog-boxes-overview?view=netdesktop-9.0
